Is it possible to automate Testcases (in manuell-Mode) to start them again after the Bug is resolved?
We create manual test cases in Azure DevOps.
During the execution of a test point, you can directly create a bug ticket, which is also linked to the test case. In addition, the result of the test point is changed from ‘Active’ to ‘Error’ in the ‘Execute’ tab.
If the bug ticket is now processed and receives the status ‘resolved’, nothing happens with the test point and it remains in the status ‘Error’.  Is there a way to automatically set this test point back to ‘Active’ and test it again? So far, we always go to Reset status.
We used Google and the Documentation to find informations, if it is possible and how it will be possible.

Glad to see you in Stack overflow. Currently there is no built-in feature to automatically reset the status of a test point from Error to Active when a linked bug is resolved. But with rest api, can partially automate the process. Please check the details below, thanks.

There is no built-in feature to automatically reset the status of a test point from Error to Active when a linked bug is resolved. The status of the test point needs to be manually reset to 'Active' for retesting.
However, you can use rest api to partically automate the process:

Based on the Bug which is resolved, we can get the testby test case(the one in test point), we can use rest api Wiql - Query By Wiql to script it.


Then according to the test case id, find the related test point with rest api Points - Get Points By Query.

At last, with test point, use rest api Points - Update to reset to active.


The whole powershell script sample as below:
# Define your parameters
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "project"
$bugId = "7742"
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Define the WIQL query
$query = @"
{
    "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.WorkItemType] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.Id] = $bugId) AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'Tested By')"
}
"@

# Define the REST API URL
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1"

# Convert the personal access token to a Base64 string
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))


# Send the REST API request and get the response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $query -Headers @{Authorization="Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json"

# Filter the workItemRelations array and output the URL of the target work item where rel is "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward"
$testcaseid = $response.workItemRelations | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward" } | ForEach-Object { $_.target.id }
$testcaseurl = $response.workItemRelations | Where-Object { $_.rel -eq "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward" } | ForEach-Object { $_.target.url }

# Output the URL
echo "test case id is:" $testcaseid               # the test case id
echo "test case url is:" $testcaseurl              # the test case url 


# Define the REST API URL
$pointurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/points?api-version=7.1-preview.2"

     
# Define the request body
$body = @"
{
  "PointsFilter": {
    "TestcaseIds": [
      $testcaseid
    ]
  }
}
"@

# Send the REST API request and get the response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pointurl -Method Post -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization="Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json"


# Output the response
echo "test point id is:" $response.points.id             # export test point id
echo "test point url is:" $response.points.url            # export test point url


$testpointurl = $response.points.url 

# Define the REST API URL
$activeurl = "$testpointurl" + "?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
     
# Define the request body
$body = @"
{
  "resetToActive": "true"
}
"@


# Send the REST API request and get the response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $activeurl -Method Patch -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization="Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json"

# Output the response
$response

The output:


I totally understand your concern, if you would like automatically reset the status of a test point from Error to Active when a linked bug is resolved, it's recommended to raise a feature request in community link here, thanks.
Edit: modify the step2 in script, so that it will test point as per the test case id, no need test suite and test plan info.
